# Run python (unix) command with very low priority

Tags: python, unix, subprocess

1. I have a py script which reads data from db and loads into CSV file as below

   ```
   with open(filePath, 'a') as myfile:
       myfile.write(myline)
   ```
2. Once the file is ready, my py script will initiate SQLLDR from subprocess.call(...) and loads all of them.

I will have to do all of the above steps with very low priority. I have set `os.nice(19)` and passed it to all my `subprocess.call(...)` function. Looks good this for step 2 above.

How can set "niceness" while creating and writing files on server? Is it possible to pass os (after setting `os.nice(19)`) while writing/reading files that way "nice" will make sure it run with low priority?

Comment: To be more clear on my question - I'm writing a file using open() and I would like to do read/write operations with very low priority on server! I'll not execute any Unix functions/commands here, I'm simply opening file "with open(files, 'a') as myfile" and using myfile to read write. This operation should run with very low priority on server. Any thoughts would be of great help!!

Answer (score 2):

By default, on linux >2.6, the io priority is computed from the nice value, meaning that low priority process will automatically have a lower IO impact, but you can specify the io priority of a process with the [ionice](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ionice) command, if you want to set it to another value.

Answer (score 1):

In general, `nice` value affects the scheduling of your process on the CPU (i.e. the share of CPU cycles you are getting and the priority), so it will hardly have any impact for the process that just *writes* data to a file. Why not run the process from the get go with an appropriately low `nice` priority?

Comment: I'm sorry to ask this, but can you please elaborate more on "Why not run the process from the get go with an appropriately low nice priority?"

Comment: I think my problem is to set *niceness* (or something similar) while reading and writing files. My script will not executing any commands while reading/writing to files :(

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the [manual for setpriority(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setpriority) upon which nice is built:

> A  child created by fork(2) inherits its parent's nice value.  The nice
>          value is preserved across execve(2).

so any Subprocesses will inherit the current nice setting. Although as Alexander notes, you won't see much difference for a process that spends most of its time waiting for disk writes to complete.